# Obtain indices corresponding to instances for each type of error in a confusion matrix in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Instead of just obtaining a confusion matrix, I want to be able to get the indices (or array mask) of the instances that committed a specific type of error. So for example, I want to see the instances predicted to be class-2 when it belonged to class-0, etc.

I can easily obtain the array mask using list comprehensions:

```
import numpy as np

y_true, y_pred = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1]), np.array([0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2])
np.array([[np.logical_and(y_true==r, y_pred==c) for c in xrange(3)] for r in xrange(3)])
```

and this yields:

```
[[[ True False  True False False False]
  [False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False]]

 [[False  True False False False False]
  [False False False False  True False]
  [False False False False False  True]]

 [[False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False]
  [False False False  True False False]]]
```

(to get the indices, I could use `np.where()`). The above corresponds to the confusion matrix:

```
[[2 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [0 0 1]]
```

However, I would like to ask if there is a `numpy`-thonic one-liner to help me do away with the nested list comprehensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add one of those confusing fancy indexing solutions to the mix, you could also do:

```
>>> y_true = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
>>> y_pred = np.array([0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2])
>>> out = np.zeros((3, 3, len(y_true)), dtype=np.bool)
>>> out[y_true, y_pred, np.arange(len(y_true))] = True
>>> out
array([[[ True, False,  True, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

       [[False,  True, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False,  True]],

       [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

---

You can get the confusion matrix summing the above matrix over the last axis, but if that's all you are after, it is probably better to build it directly with `np.bincount`:

```
>>> np.bincount(y_pred + 3*y_true, minlength=9).reshape(3,3)
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

SciPy's `sparse_coo` matrices add together repeated indices, so the following also works:

```
>>> sps.coo_matrix((np.ones_like(y_true, dtype=np.intp),
---                 (y_true, y_pred)), shape=(3, 3)).A
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I've been thinking about whether or not its possible to adapt this to the initialization of a `coo_matrix` using the last set of arguments defined in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix (`coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), [shape=(M, N)])`), but all this array indexing hurting my brain. Do you have any thought?

Comment: See my edit, I think we have fallen for the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/223106), there are better options to build the confusion matrix than creating your boolean array.

Comment: Yeah, this is more or less the same as this https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py#L897 but I do need the array mask or indices corresponding to each entry in the confusion matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite a one-liner:

```
In [42]: y_true = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1])

In [43]: y_pred = np.array([0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2])

In [44]: n = len(y_pred)

In [45]: values = np.arange(3).reshape(-1,1)

In [46]: np.logical_and((y_true == values).reshape(-1,1,n), (y_pred == values).reshape(1,-1,n))
Out[46]: 
array([[[ True, False,  True, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

       [[False,  True, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False,  True]],

       [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

A somewhat briefer spelling of the same expression:

```
In [100]: (y_true == values).reshape(-1,1,n) & (y_pred == values)
Out[100]: 
array([[[ True, False,  True, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False]],

       [[False,  True, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False,  True]],

       [[False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I am very conflicted about which answer to accept. I like this in that it is clear and intuitive, but I asked the question in hopes that someone would provide an advanced indexing solution which @Jaime has done. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No need to be conflicted, @Jaime's answer is pretty slick.